# how to download file from Google cloud storage using python

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-storage, software-design

I am working with Google Cloud Storage via Python, so wanted to know how to download the file via Python code.
I know, a similar example is given in documentation but wanted to know the best way to authenticate via credentials.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage documentation includes examples in Python.

Comment: Correct @John, but wanted to know the best way to authenticate the credentials apart from IAM(Identity and Access Management).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by **apart from IAM**. IAM is the authorization mechanism. Again, there are numerous examples showing authorization with Cloud Storage as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:
Install:

```
pip3 install google-cloud-storage
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Step 2:
Followed by [authenticating](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) yourself using credentials(like project id, private key, private key_id, client email, and client id).

Step 3:
From official documentation on [Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python):

```py
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob."""

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to file path {}. successfully ".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```